# Как получить id в Sugar ORM?

Tags: java, android, orm, sugarorm

У меня есть записи в базе данных, хочу через адаптер поместить их в cardview, но для этого мне нужен id этих записей, каким образом это сделать?

UPD: В документации я не понял, как получать id. Я понимаю что поидее должен использовать getId, но как именно, что бы получить все Id из базы и запихнуть его в адаптер, я не понимаю.

```
    public class book extends SugarRecord {

    @Unique
    String title;
    String edition;
    private Long id;

    public book(){
    }

    public book(String title, String edition){
        this.title = title;
        this.edition = edition;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "book{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", edition='" + edition + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
   List<book> books = SugarRecord.listAll(book.class);

    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(book.findById(book.class,44)));


    ArrayList<String> myDataset = getDataSet();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

private ArrayList<String> getDataSet() {
    List<book> books = SugarRecord.listAll(book.class);
    ArrayList<String> mDataSet = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
        mDataSet.add(i, "item" + i);
    }
    return mDataSet;
}
```

Comment: Будет полезно, если вы укажете какие ссылки и по каким поисковым запросам не выдали вам результат. И что непонятно из документации. Ещё **немного** кода не помешает в вопросе.

Comment: SugarRecord.listAll(book.class) Вот ошибка. Снизу ответ гляньте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю надо что-то типа такого?

```
private ArrayList<Long> getDataSet() {
    List<Book> books = Book.listAll(Book.class);
    ArrayList<Long> mDataSet = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
        mDataSet.add(books.get(i).getId());
    }
    return mDataSet;
}
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель!

Answer (score 2):

id Вам не нужен. Чтобы достать все записи из таблицы используйте следующий код

```
List<Record> recordsList = Record.listAll(Record.class)
```

Соответственно подставьте вместо Record название своего класса

Comment: Но в данном случая случая он мне выкатит всю таблицу или теперь мне необходимо распарсить ее?

Comment: Если честно я не особо понимаю зачем нужен метод getDataSet(). Вы хотели список книг или список циферок?

Comment: Book , это было просто название класса, не какого смысла она не несет. Сама же программа у меня разрабатывается как словарь, в базе же хранится к примеру название элемента, его описание и id. id мне нужен был, для того что бы автоматически строить список из card_view, но многоуважаемый Viktor все сделал уже за меня, мне осталось только подставить и воуля, список работает. А getDataset для работы с данными.

Answer (score 1):

`Sugar` сам создает `id`. Его можно не добавлять самостоятельно.

А получить `id` можно так:

```
long id = book.save();
```

либо так:

```
book.save();
long id = book.getId();
```